# Win32 ListView Header Drawing Issues

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I have a subclassed ListView that's being resized with the parent window. To resize it I'm doing:

```
SetWindowPos(lv, HWND_TOP, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom - rc.top, 0);
```

The ListView is created and subclassed with:

```
    HWND lv = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, L"45",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_EX_STATICEDGE | 
        LVS_REPORT | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        0, 28, 300, 400, hwnd, 0, NULL, NULL);

    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(lv, 
        LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);

    SetWindowSubclass(lv, (SUBCLASSPROC)ListViewProc, (UINT_PTR)1, 0);
```

However I'm encountering some drawing issues related to the header. After resizing the ListView, it appears thus:

[image]

When altering the header column width through dragging the column edges, it appears thus:

[image]

Note the one pixel difference in the height of the header. I'm thinking it's an issue with the ordering of `WM_PAINT` messages, but I'm not sure why this is happening or how to prevent it.

How might this issue be fixed?

Comment: I guess I'd start by disabling the subclass and see if that makes a difference; if so, you know where to look.

Comment: Turns out I was using `SetWindowPos()` on the ListView Header when handling `WM_SIZE` in the ListView proc. What was causing the issue appears to have been the `SWP_NOZORDER`. I'm considering deleting this question though because I'm not sure whether it can be of use to anyone.